# Rotating a conic equation

Tags: rotations

Identify the type of conic, transform the equation in *x* and *y* into equation in X and Y (without an XY term) by rotating the x- and y- axes by $θ=30^\circ$ to arrive at the new X- and Y- axes and graph the resulting equation showing both sets of axes.

$7x^2 + 4\sqrt{3}xy + 3y^2 - 9 = 0$

**EDIT: There was a typo. It is fixed**

Comment: Umm.  That's not really a conic equation as it stands.  Are you sure the equation is supposed to have that $\sqrt{x}$ term?

Comment: That was a typo. It has been fixed.

Comment: You can look at the discriminant = $(4\sqrt{3})^2-4\cdot 7\cdot 3 = -36$ to determine that you have an ellipse.  What are you having problems with?

Comment: Since you know what must be done, why don't you do it?

Comment: I don't know how to write the equation in terms of X and Y

Comment: You want $x = X \cos 30^{\circ} - Y \sin 30^{\circ}$ and $y = X \sin 30^{\circ} +Y \cos 30^{\circ}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos30^\circ & -\sin30^\circ\\ \sin30^\circ & \cos30^\circ\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}X \\ Y\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{3} & -1\\ 1 & \sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}X \\ Y\end{pmatrix}$.

Then do the substitution.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very nicely in the complex plane. We first convert to polar form with $x=r\cos\theta,\,y=r\sin\theta$ so that

$$7x^2 + 4\sqrt{3}xy + 3y^2 - 9 = 0\to r^2(7\cos^2\theta+4\sqrt{3}\cos\theta\sin\theta+3\sin^2\theta)=9\\
r=\sqrt{\frac{9}{7\cos^2\theta+4\sqrt{3}\cos\theta\sin\theta+3\sin^2\theta}}$$

Then we can say

$$z=re^{i\theta},\quad \theta\in[0,2\pi]$$

And finally, *any* rotation, say $z_{\theta_0}$, is given by $z_{\theta_0}=ze^{i\theta_0}$.